# R: Converting characters to numbers in an R data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rvest

A question regarding this data extraction I did. I would like to create a bar chart with the data but unfortunately I am unable to convert the characters extracted to numbers inside R. If I edit the file in a text editor, there's no porblem at all but I'd like to do the whole process in R. Here it is the code:

```
    install.packages("rvest")
    library(rvest)

     url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_tax"

     corporatetax <- url %>% 
     read_html() %>% 
     html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[5]') %>% 
     html_table()

     str(corporatetax)
```

As a result in `corporatetax` there is a data.frame with 3 variables all of them characters. My question, which I've not been abe to resolve, is how should I proceed to convert the second and the third column to numbers to create a bar chart? I've tried with sapply() and dplyr() but did not find a correct way to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried as.numeric and apply it to each of the columns you want to convert? e.g. df$column_1 <- as.numeric(df$column_1)

Comment: you probably will need to remove the non-numeric character, like "%" first, I usually use `gsub()` for this

Comment: and right now, `corporatetax` is a list, not a data.frame. extract the data.frame with `corporatetax[[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

You might try to clean up the table like this

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_tax"

corporatetax <- url %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  # your xpath defines the single table, so you can use html_node() instead of html_nodes()
  html_node(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[5]') %>% 
  html_table() %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  setNames(c("country", "corporate_tax", "combined_tax"))

corporatetax %>% 
  mutate(corporate_tax=as.numeric(str_replace(corporate_tax, "%", ""))/100,
         combined_tax=as.numeric(str_replace(combined_tax, "%", ""))/100
         )
```